# Vim - How to change name style for files open in tabs

Tags: vim

When I open multiple files in tabs in vim, it truncates their filenames at the top. Additionally, it truncates them from the start. For example:

```
vim -p convert_places_for_dynamo.py es_sculptures_upload.py google_places.py dyn_sculptures_upload.py
```

The tabs are shown as:

```
places_for_dynamo.py| sculptures_upload.py| google_places.py| sculptures_upload.py
```

Is there a way that I can format it so that it truncates the end instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change tab titles in vim to user-define names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322079/how-to-change-tab-titles-in-vim-to-user-define-names)

Comment: you'll have to write your own tab label code. See the question I linked.